# Dockerfile からイメージを作成したい

Tags: python, windows, docker

ビルドをしたい。（windowsです）

コマンドプロンプトに以下を入力

`docker build -t jlab:latest /Users/name/Desktop/MyDocker`

実行すると、

```
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker build --help'.

Usage: docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Build an image from a Dockerfile
```

となってしまう。
私が使用させていただいているYouTubeによると、Succesfully builtとなれば完了とのこと。

以下の3つを試しましたが、変化なしです。

- ①Dockerfileを保存してあるディレクトリを””で括る
- ②Dockerfile が保存されたディレクトリに移動してから `docker build -t jlab:latest .`のように実行する
- ③`docker build -t jlab:latest -f /path/to/Dockerfile`と`-f` オプションで Dockerfile を指定

追加です。私のパスに空白がありました。Dockerfileを保存してあるディレクトリーを””で囲ったところ、上記のようにはなりませんでしたが、以下のようになってしまいました。

```
invalid argument "jlab:latest\\Users\\FamilyName△FirstName\\Desktop\\MyDocker" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format
See 'docker build --help'.
```

どなたかご教示ください。

Comment: /Users/name/Desktop/MyDocker は Dockerfile の置いてあるディレクトリですか？

Comment: 追記されたエラーは当初と別物ですので、本スレッドは解決済みとして、新たな質問を投稿されることをお勧めします。新たな質問を追加されると質問と回答の対応が取れなくなるためです。

Comment: もともと書かれていた error during connect のエラーは起こらなくなったと考えて良いですか？

Comment: はい、そのようなエラーは起こらなくなりました。

Comment: Windows なのにパスの指定方法が Unix っぽいのが気になっているのですが、どのような実行環境を使ってらっしゃるのでしょうか。

Comment: atomを使い、コマンドプロンプトで実行しております。

Comment: 私の回答では、どこからどこまでをダブルクオートで括るべきかを例示していますが、それに従わず、異なる個所にダブルクオートを挿入する理由を教えてください。

Comment: ログイン名等を伏せ字にするのは構わないので、あなたが実際に試した手順や環境をそのまま記してください。現状では書き方が不十分で、第三者が詳しい判断をするのは難しいと思います。 / ヘルプページも参考にしてください。 - https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: 異なる個所にダブルクオートというのは、私自身のパスではなく、入力語に返ってきたものです。ご確認宜しくお願い致します。また、私が入力したパスは次のようです。docker build -t jlab:latest"/Users/FamilyName△FirstName/Desktop/MyDocker"すると、invalid argument "jlab:latest\\Users\\FamilyName△FirstName\\Desktop\\MyDocker" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format
See 'docker build --help'.と返ってきてしまいます。

Comment: ある人からは-fを付け加えるようにと言われましたが、それが正しければ、どこに付け加えるべきなのでしょう。

Comment: やはり質問文に書かれていたものとはパスが違ったのですね……。であれば sayuri さんの回答でこの問題については解決します。追加の疑問については別の質問になりますので、別途ご投稿ください……と思ったら、既にこちらでご投稿済みでした https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/74915/19110

Answer (score 4):

エラーメッセージの通りです。

> "docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.

dockerともWindowsとも関係なく、コンピューターにおけるプログラムの起動方法としての一般論です。引数は空白などで区切られるため、Path名に空白が含まれていると分割して解釈されます。`""`で括り、`"/Users/name/Desktop/MyDocker"`等することで一つの文字列であることをプログラムに明示する必要があります。

Answer (score 1):

Dockerfile が保存されたディレクトリに移動してから以下のように実行するか、

```
docker build -t jlab:latest .
```

`-f` オプションで Dockerfile を指定してみてください。

```
docker build -t jlab:latest -f /path/to/Dockerfile
```