# Dockerを使ってPythonのデータ分析の環境構築をしたい

Tags: docker, windows-10

プログラミング学習チャンネルのキノコード（YouTubeチャンネル）を使って進めている。
流れとしては、Windows上にUbuntuというLinuxのOSを立てて、そこにAnacondaをインストールする。そして、Pythonでのデータ分析環境としてJupyter Labを立ち上げる。

Windows 10 Proまたは Windows 10 Enterpriseの場合はそのままDocker for Windowsが使用できるが、Windows 10 Homeであるため、まずはWSL2をインストールする。

https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/wsl/install-win10 を参考に試みたが、Ubuntuのインストール後、名前やパスワードを設定する画面にならない。

```
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x800701bc
Error: 0x800701bc WSL 2 ???????????? ??????????????????????? https://aka.ms/wsl2kernel ?????????
Press any key to continue...
```

このようなエラーが発生し、文字入力すると画面が閉じてしまう。

解決策としては、以下を管理者権限で起動したpowershellで実行するようです。

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
```

実行してから、再度Ubuntuを実行すると、エラーが出なくなるはずです。

しかし、

```
Path :
Online : True
RestartNeeded : False
```

のようになってしまいます。

調べてみると、WSL2のインストールは難しいようなので、
設定が簡単なDocker Toolboxを使ってインストールする。

進めていくと、Docker Toolboxは非推奨になり、現在活発に開発がされていないようなので、代わりにDockerデスクトップを使用する。

Dockerデスクトップを起動すると

```
Try running a container: Copy and paste this command into your terminal and then come back

docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started
```

とあるので、コマンドプロンプトで実行すると

```
docker: error during connect: Post https://192.168.99.100:2376/v1.24/containers/create: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:2376: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

となり、先に進めない

Comment: 元々何をインストールしていて、そこに何をインストールなさいましたか？　具体的に参考にした URL と共に手順をひとつずつ書くよう [edit] して追記くださいませんでしょうか。というのも、歴史的経緯により Windows 向けの Docker 環境は[複数あり](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/2011/20/news015.html)、複雑なためです。たとえば "Docker for Windows" と "Docker Desktop for Windows" という別々のものが存在します。また、Docker Desktop for Windows を Windows Home で使うためには WSL 2 バックエンドが必要なため、そのあたりに触れられていないのも気になっています。

Comment: 「Python の環境を構築する」ということで Python タグが付いているようですが、質問の範囲では直接 Python のコードに関わる内容は含まれていないため、このタグは不要と思います。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Comment: DockerデスクトップのsettingsでExposing daemon on TCPで始まる設定にチェックを入れていますか？いれていない場合チェックを入れて「docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started」を実行するとどうなりますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。変化なしです。